# Is there a general argument about return style for a "conditional" method?

Tags: java, coding-style

I've seen a lot of methods in these two style:

```
1.
void foo() {
  if(!good) {
    return;
  }
  doFoo();
}

2.
void foo() {
  if(good) {
    doFoo();
  }
}
```

I wonder if this is just a matter of taste or one is actually better than the other. Does anyone know any evidence about this? (Style-checker rules, book, etc.)
I'm thinking mainly about this code written in Java.

Comment: If the code is just so simple then no much diff. If many nested if/else in your function, then write less level of nested if/else statements will be better.

Comment: negative conditions are harder to understand than positive conditions so I would go for option 2, which happens to be shorter, which is good too.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your project team's code style rules.

If `if` statement checks method contracts I prefer `fast fail` approach.

Answer (score 0):

i believe its all depend on your program logic and requirements, In your first example doFoo() will be called only if your if condition is not satisfied and in your second option doFoo() will be called when if condition is satisfied..

you can read coding convention for java programmer it is pretty good http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it's very basic so doesn't tell about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Between these two, second option is better IMHO. If there are more `if-else` branches, you could end up with multiple `return` statements which makes the code hard to navigate (in most cases, but sometimes it does good to your code).

Answer (score 0):

First variant handle extra nesting. It depends on your project's code style conventions and your method logic.
I advice you to read [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)